# Slick slider mobile:first param not working (responsive not working)

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, slick.js

I have `slick slider` implemented on a module and here's a summary of how I'm wanting it to function:

- `<= 767px` screen width: show dots (no arrows) and `1 slide`.
- `>= 768px`: hide dots, show custom arrows and show `2 slides`.
- `>= 992px`: Show `2.5 slides` with no dots, and custom arrows (should inherit from above breakpoint settings).
- `>= 1200px`: Show `3.2 slides`
- `>= 1600px`: Show `3.5 slides`

**Current behaviour**

The default setting works. It shows the dots and one slide for `<= 767px`. However, when I test on a `iPad` `(768px`), it removes the dots (which is good), shows the arrows (which is good), but still only shows the 1 slide, when I have `2` defined. Then on anything above this width, it is still showing one slide.

I have `mobileFirst: true` defined, so unsure why it's like this?

See demo here:

```js
$(function() {

  var $slider = $("#section-slick");

  var slickOptions = {
    slidesToShow: 1,
    slidesToScroll: 1,
    arrows: false,
    dots: true,
    // infinite: true,
    mobileFirst: true,
    autoplay: false,
    fade: true,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 767,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
          prevArrow: $(".section__nav-prev"),
          nextArrow: $(".section__nav-next"),
          mobileFirst: false,
          arrows: true,
          dots: false,
          infinite: false,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 991,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2.5,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 1199,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3.2,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 1599,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3.5,
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  $($slider).slick(slickOptions);

  $(window).on('resize orientationchange', function() {
    $($slider).slick("resize");
  });

});
```

```css
:root {
  --black: #000000;
  --white: #FFFFFF;
  --grey: #707070;
  --green: #00FF97;
}

section__nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

section__nav-next {
  margin-left: 26px;
}

section__nav-arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
}

section__nav-arrow svg:hover path {
  fill: var(--green);
}

section__nav-arrow.slick-disabled {
  opacity: 0.3;
  pointer-events: none;
}

section figure {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/slick-carousel/1.8.1/slick.min.js" integrity="sha512-XtmMtDEcNz2j7ekrtHvOVR4iwwaD6o/FUJe6+Zq+HgcCsk3kj4uSQQR8weQ2QVj1o0Pk6PwYLohm206ZzNfubg==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<section class="section">

  <div class="container d-none d-md-block">
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
      <div class="col-2">
        <div class="section__nav">
          <div class="section__nav-arrow section__nav-prev">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="13.503" height="23.619" viewBox="0 0 13.503 23.619">
              <path data-name="Icon ionic-ios-arrow-back" d="M15.321,18l8.937-8.93a1.688,1.688,0,0,0-2.391-2.384L11.742,16.8a1.685,1.685,0,0,0-.049,2.327L21.86,29.321a1.688,1.688,0,0,0,2.391-2.384Z" transform="translate(-11.251 -6.194)" />
            </svg>
          </div>
          <div class="section__nav-arrow section__nav-next">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="13.503" height="23.619" viewBox="0 0 13.503 23.619">
              <path data-name="Icon ionic-ios-arrow-back" d="M20.683,18,11.746,9.07a1.688,1.688,0,0,1,2.391-2.384L24.262,16.8a1.685,1.685,0,0,1,.049,2.327L14.144,29.321a1.688,1.688,0,0,1-2.391-2.384Z" transform="translate(-11.251 -6.194)" />
            </svg>
          </div>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div id="section-slick">

          <figure>Card 1</figure>
          <figure>Card 2</figure>
          <figure>Card 3</figure>
          <figure>Card 4</figure>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```

Answer (score 1):

**Problems & Fixes**

- included missing slick CSS
- removed `fade: true` property
- added `breakpoint: 480`

```js
$(function() {

  var $slider = $("#section-slick");

  var slickOptions = {
    prevArrow: $(".section__nav-prev"),
    nextArrow: $(".section__nav-next"),
    mobileFirst: true,
    autoplay: false,
    responsive: [{
        breakpoint: 480,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 1,
          arrows: false,
          dots: true,
          infinite: false,
          mobileFirst: true,
        }
      }, {
        breakpoint: 767,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 991,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 2.5,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 1199,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3.2,
        }
      },
      {
        breakpoint: 1599,
        settings: {
          slidesToShow: 3.5,
        }
      }
    ]
  };

  $slider.slick(slickOptions);

});
```

```css
:root {
  --black: #000000;
  --white: #FFFFFF;
  --grey: #707070;
  --green: #00FF97;
}

section__nav {
  display: flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  padding: 50px 0;
}

section__nav-next {
  margin-left: 26px;
}

section__nav-arrow {
  cursor: pointer;
}

section__nav-arrow svg:hover path {
  fill: var(--green);
}

section__nav-arrow.slick-disabled {
  opacity: 0.3;
  pointer-events: none;
}

section figure {
  padding: 50px;
  background-color: var(--black);
  color: var(--white);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.6.0/jquery.min.js" integrity="sha512-894YE6QWD5I59HgZOGReFYm4dnWc1Qt5NtvYSaNcOP+u1T9qYdvdihz0PPSiiqn/+/3e7Jo4EaG7TubfWGUrMQ==" crossorigin="anonymous" referrerpolicy="no-referrer"></script>
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/bootstrap@5.0.2/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" integrity="sha384-EVSTQN3/azprG1Anm3QDgpJLIm9Nao0Yz1ztcQTwFspd3yD65VohhpuuCOmLASjC" crossorigin="anonymous">

<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" />
<script type="text/javascript" src="//cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<section class="section">

  <div class="container d-none d-md-block">
    <div class="row justify-content-end">
      <div class="col-2">
        <div class="section__nav">
          <button class="section__nav-arrow section__nav-prev">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="13.503" height="23.619" viewBox="0 0 13.503 23.619">
              <path data-name="Icon ionic-ios-arrow-back" d="M15.321,18l8.937-8.93a1.688,1.688,0,0,0-2.391-2.384L11.742,16.8a1.685,1.685,0,0,0-.049,2.327L21.86,29.321a1.688,1.688,0,0,0,2.391-2.384Z" transform="translate(-11.251 -6.194)" />
            </svg>
          </button>
          <button class="section__nav-arrow section__nav-next">
            <svg xmlns="http://www.w3.org/2000/svg" width="13.503" height="23.619" viewBox="0 0 13.503 23.619">
              <path data-name="Icon ionic-ios-arrow-back" d="M20.683,18,11.746,9.07a1.688,1.688,0,0,1,2.391-2.384L24.262,16.8a1.685,1.685,0,0,1,.049,2.327L14.144,29.321a1.688,1.688,0,0,1-2.391-2.384Z" transform="translate(-11.251 -6.194)" />
            </svg>
          </button>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="container">
    <div class="row">
      <div class="col-12">
        <div id="section-slick">

          <figure>Card 1</figure>
          <figure>Card 2</figure>
          <figure>Card 3</figure>
          <figure>Card 4</figure>

        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</section>
```